# Python 2.7 Regular Expressions: Extract 3rd Hex Value from Text String

Tags: python

I want to extract the 3rd hex number from the string below using regular expressions. I can't seem to get the regular expressions correct.

I have a string below:

```
    s = ('0x11111111 0x22222222 0x33333333 0x44444444')
    x = re.compile((0x)+(\w+))
```

Code:

```
    value = re.search(x, s)
    if value:
            result = int(value.group(2),16)
            print hex(result)
```

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression? Why not `s.split(' ')[2]`

Comment: It's mainly for practice. I do agree split is way more efficient  though :)

Comment: I usually use a site like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to test and get my regular expressions working before moving back into python.

Comment: Great tip! Yes, I've been messing around with this website as well. I'll have to learn more about the re.search vs. re.findall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `re.findall`

```
s = '0x11111111 0x22222222 0x33333333 0x44444444'
x = re.compile(r'\w+')

# Use find all to get a list of all matching elements
values = x.findall(s)
if values:
        # Extract the wanted element (you should really check
        # len of string or better catch IndexError)
        result = int(values[2], 16)
        print(hex(result))
```